# PhpStorm - Cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I try to lookup the declaration of `File` but PhpStorm says `Cannot find declaration to go to`.

[image]

I also tried it with netbeans, it can't find the declartion too.
I also tried to lookup the alias `use File;`

[image]

I get `No usage found in project files`.

How does my code even know what it has to do if It can't find any declarations? This makes no sense to me.

How can I find out where `File` is declared?

Comment: your autoloader manages that, need to look up how it works for your project.

Comment: If it is laravels' facade, try Laravel IDE Helper https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/

Comment: Load all files from the server to your local workspace (like you have open all files in phpstorm), after that the declaration should be found (Maybe refresh index in phpstorm).

Comment: SideNote: Whoe added `use File;` ?? That is not valid namespace for a class, because if it is in global namespace there are no named spaces so `new \File()` will do the same in `_autoloader`, So why `use File;`?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions im not sure, I learned it like this on tutorials

Comment: Plz tell us the version of lavravel. And look here: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/index.html

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions If the current file is in a namespace, unprefixed classes will be looked up in the current namespace, *not* the global namespace. `use ClassName` will import from the global namespace. Compare https://3v4l.org/m2tTa vs https://3v4l.org/HPIeC

Comment: I am using the latest version 5.4.15

Comment: @IMSoP OK, got it. But then `File` is NOT from/under `Illuminate`?  Wired. Like the doc page for that laravel.com/api/5.4/index.html can not find `File` anywhere there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does my code even know what it has to do if It can't find any declarations?

By [using an autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). This is basically a function which is called whenever an unknown class is referenced, and attempts to define it, usually by including a file according to some naming convention. You will need to find how your particular framework manages this.

Note that it's possible it's including a file from outside the directory you have set up as the "project" in your IDE. Once you've figured out where it is, you may be able to configure your IDE to know about these extra files.

> How can I find out where File is declared?

Find a place where the class is used, and using a debugger or just "dump value and die", you can use [ReflectionClass::getFilename()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php) to find out about it:

```
$r = new \ReflectionClass(File::class);
$r->getFilename();
```

Note that the `File::class` syntax (available since PHP 5.5) gives you the fully qualified name of the class, ignoring any aliasing or namespace imports.

It's also possible for an *extension* (a library written in C, not PHP) to define a class. In that case, `ReflectionClass::getFilename()` will return `false`, and you'll need to use [`ReflectionClass::getExtensionName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getextensionname.php), then track down the documentation for that extension.

Comment: Hmm, I get `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ReflectionClass' not found`

Comment: @EdwardBlack Ah, sorry, `\ReflectionClass`, to avoid the incorrect namespace lookup

Comment: Does someone know if there is a way how I can teach my IDE where to find these declarations?

Comment: @EdwardBlack Try checking the link in 2nd comment (for actual question) again -- barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper does just that -- translates Laravel's magic into more understandable for IDE form.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is quite "opinionated" in the way they use facades.

Apart from the [PHPStorm gudelines](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/) how to deal with it, I find `artisan tinker` a simplest IDE-independent way to get familiar with new codebase.

The command provides a REPL shell, so if you are curious of where the `File` is actually defined, just invoke it, to get some information from the error message:

```
>>> File::delete()
PHP warning:  Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::delete(), called in /path/to/project/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 213 and defined in /path/to/project/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 118
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPStrom scans all files in Project Root folder. Add an external library (framework) you use to Project Root folder. Maybe you should instal dependecies via composer.